# Memory Attacks on 64-bit machines (Is this article out to lunch?!)

Tags: windows-7, macos, security, 64-bit

I just finished reading an article on [Remote BSOD errors on Windows 7](http://www.electronista.com/articles/09/09/08/windows.7.returns.remote.bsod/) and I had a question about the content.  Specifically this line:

> Apple's software [...] has gotten more secure with the latest release, whose 64-bit memory space prevents certain kinds of memory attacks from working properly.

To me this statement (although correct) seems absurd since a windows system running 64-bit memory would also prevent certain kinds of memory attacks from working as well.

Is there a gap in my knowledge of Mac/Windows 64-bit memory?  Or did the article *fail* to mention this for Windows?

Comment: +2 for insight. -1 for a potential Mac vs Win fanbois war.

Comment: I doubt Mac OS is any more secure than Windows. It's just targeted less.

Comment: @alex oh ho, now you must die for saying that!! :)

Comment: @alex: You're pretty much right. I've commonly heard that Leopard was less secure than Vista, but due to being targeted less, was safer. Snow Leopard was supposed to come closer security-wise, but a large targeting base is what lets exploits get found, exploited, and fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be correct, that 64-bit Windows also benefits from address randomization across a wider range to better prevent brute-force memory address attacks. Since the Windows bug in the article is network-related, I think it's irrelevant to 64-bitness.

Apple's statement is even more misleading, since only the newest Macs even boot into a 64-bit kernel in Snow Leopard, while most macs will still be using a 32-bit kernel and don't get this additional security benefit at all. See [this article](http://gizmodo.com/5343443/snow-leopard-currently-restricts-64+bit-booting-to-newer-macs) for a reference.

Comment: Ah, but applications recompiled in 64 bit such as Safari will gain better defense against such attacks. Kernel, no. Apps, yes.

Comment: @scoopdreams: Do you have a reference for that? From what I understand, either 2 things are going on: 64-bit applications are translated to 32-bit on the fly by the OS where they might just use a 32-bit address space, or the universal binaries contain 32-bit and 64-bit versions (which many applications do now, universal binaries are not only for combining PPC/Intel)

Comment: Never mind, I suppose my own article addresses that and says the same thing, so I probably just don't really understand how they accomplish this.

Comment: Even if the kernel boots in 32-bit mode, most apps run in 64-bit mode with 64-bit address space (assuming you have a capable CPU, of course).